How do ultra light high power BLDC motors achieve such high power-to-weight ratios?
I was searching for high power/torque density of BLDC motors, but when I compare the commercially accessible ones to ultra high end motors, they always make the commercial ones bite the dust.
For example, the Evolito's Axial Flux motors can achieve 350 kilowatts of output power while only weighing 30kg.
I tried to search the subject on my own, but the only ways I could find in order to make electric motors more powerful would be to increase their size both in magnetic core and winding.
Simply doing that always increases the motor weight to hundreds of kilograms or even thousands.
I also heard that high resolution pulse modulators/controllers would allow the motor to decrease its windings by 10 times, but I don't know if that is true, nor even how it works.
I also heard that they use highly expensive silver wires or similar, but I couldn't find any information if that is actually true.
How do they do it? How do they achieve such extreme power to weight ratios while maintaining efficiency and performance?

Simple, they leave out the yolks. Everyone knows eggs are fattening. (Typo in the website description).

Easy. They cheat. Like 2000W speakers 30 years ago.

@TQQQ I didn't get it?

They claim 350kW - it's usually what they can put out for a second, then they would need to shut of the motor and let it cool. Same as PMPO watts in speakers 30 years ago, it was a way to inflate a number without actually having a more powerful device.

How do they make the motors efficent and lightweight?
By using different materials that are more lightweight where they can and also by using a two rotor system.

Building with lightweight polymer instead of heavier metals, when
possible, Harris said, is among the ways the company wants to sell
cost-effective, streamlined products that can be more easily mass
produced. The YASA motor includes a steel backplane for magnets, for
instance, while Evolito uses polymer instead.
...
The Evolito axial motor has two rotors with the magnets opposing each
other and a stator in the center to provide the magnetic field that
drives the rotating armature, generating the electric current. A
stator in turbine engines, in contrast, guides the flow of fluids
between rotating parts.
Chopping the stator of the Evolito motor into two halves is designed
to add safety through redundancy, Harris said, while minimizing weight
on the axial motors reduces the risk that parts of the motor could
break through their containment and damage the aircraft.

https://evtol.news/news/evolitos-breakthrough-axial-motors
Here is the patent that may be related to the lightweight materials:
https://patents.google.com/patent/EP2773023A1/en
Here is one related to some of their unique magnet arrangements that help them generate better torque with lower weight:

Source: https://patents.google.com/patent/US10566866B2/en

I don't choose to go through the song and dance of requesting a datasheet from them, but I'm seeing what look like liquid cooling ports on the linked motors which is probably why their numbers look good on paper.
Of course you, the end user, have to find a way of getting rid of 17.5 kW of thermal energy even at 95% efficiency (and designing and integrating a liquid cooling system). It does make sense to assume a separate cooling system on their projected use case of aerial vehicles, but their marketing department has left that part out.


How do they do it? How do they achieve such extreme power to weight ratios while maintaining efficiency and performance?

Well, that's scaling of a given design.  The design itself however has some scale-invariant (or, it still varies with scale, but in a consistent manner) power density, characteristic of the material and geometry of the components it's made of: what types of magnets, what size and shape, placement, core materials, windings, etc..
Without knowing the precise design in question, we can't exactly calculate what that power density should be (but also, doing those calculations takes significant effort, i.e. 3D-modeling the entire design and putting it into a 3D field simulator to determine the torque constant, core and copper losses, probably a CFD (computational fluid dynamics) simulator to model windage or coolant frictional losses, etc.), but suffice it to say, it varies between designs, and highly optimized designs today can do astonishingly well indeed.
Such designs need not be a threat to the production and use of conventional (radial-field, induction, etc.) motors, which may be cheaper to produce -- despite their greater size, the simplicity of design may win out -- or to operate, as PMSM/BLDC motors generally require a ESC/VFD whereas conventional motors can simply be switched to the mains (perhaps with some starting circuitry to ease inrush), and efficiency may vary.
